# ubuntu one (client) on a server

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have several remote servers (without gui). I am using vim as my editor. On my desktop I sync my vim files (.vimrc .vim/plugins etc) with Ubuntu One. So I can use vim files on other desktops. But I want to use them also on my servers.

Can I use Ubuntu One without installing  (apt-get install ubuntuone-client) 154 newly packages with 49.9MB of archives?

Comment: You can, but it's GUI dependent from my understanding. So you'll end up with xserver on your server.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ubuntu One for managing dotfiles seems like an overkill. I prefer using Git (or any other version control system) to synchronize configuration between multiple machines. Thanks to this I can maintain the full history of changes, merge overlapping modifications easily, and get all the power that comes with version control when needed.

PS. If you like you can take a look at [my dotfiles](https://github.com/alpha/dotfiles).

Comment: +1 for a good solution.  (Doesn't answer the question, but perhaps gets to the intent of the question.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to run Ubuntu One headless without the GUI right now.

Comment: Could you please explain why?